# Create a HTML table from JSON

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a rails application that I'm converting to be angularjs.

From a rest API, I am getting JSON like:

```
[{"id":1,"products":{"type":"Mustang","color":"blue"},"created_at":"2013-12-02T01:05:20.956Z","updated_at":"2013-12-02T01:05:20.956Z"}]
```

My angular at the moment just loops through the JSON and prints out the entire data column:

```
<tr ng-repeat="row in rows">
    <td><a href='#'>THIS IS -> </a>{{row.data}}</td>
</tr>
```

Basically, I'd like to take from the data column, the key and the value, and create a HTML table based off it. The problem is the data can vary, so not always will a key/value like: " type: Mustang" be the first, and sometimes a value will be empty but a key won't.

I asked a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19322910/dynamic-display-of-an-array-of-hashes-in-a-html-table) a while back, and got a fantastic [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19323140/1462711). The **Solution 2**  works perfectly for Ruby, but I'd like to convert it to angularjs for my project.

Thanks for all help!

Comment: if data structure will be inconsistent, likely best to do some mapping before passing it to controller. Not even clear what json data you want to map to columns...nothing matches the html. You can define columns, then use those to map arrays of rows  and cells, use arrays to `ng-repeat` both rows and cells

Comment: could be more specific? what if there is missing key -- should the value be displayed and column for be empty or such a record should not be displayed at all?

Comment: @arturgrzesiak, Thanks for the response. There should always be a key, but sometimes the value corresponding to that key will be empty. In these cases, it should just show a blank column.

Comment: The JSON has nested objects, specifically the 'products' object, while the similar question you refer to just has a flat structure. Can you clarify how you would like this nesting handled, in terms of the final output? Keeping this nesting visually can complicate things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To convert your Ruby solution in an AngularJS fashion, you can use a third party library like [UnderscoreJS](http://underscorejs.org/) to transform your JSON as you want.

So, you can first retrieve the list of products from your rest API response:

```
var rows = [{"id":1,"products":{"type":"Mustang","color":"blue"},"created_at":"2013-12-02T01:05:20.956Z","updated_at":"2013-12-02T01:05:20.956Z"}, ...]
$scope.products = _.pluck(rows, 'products'); // make a list of the products property of each row
```

Then, you can compute your headers:

```
$scope.headers = _.chain($scope.products)
                  .map(_.keys) // take the keys of each product
                  .reduce(function(a, b) {
                            return _.union(a, b);
                          }, []) // merge all keys without double
                  .value();
```

Finally, you can display your table by iterating on headers and products:

```
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th ng-repeat="key in headers">{{ key }}</th>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="product in products">
      <td ng-repeat="key in headers">{{ product[key] }}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

If a product has not a given key then it will not display anything.

Take a look at this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/GvOfFJHKK5Pme7RWoIrV?p=preview).

An utility library like Underscore is really convenient to manipulate data in a functional fashion. I advise you to look over the API and documentation.

Answer (score 0):

You can set this up as a directive in place of ng-repeat (which is just a directive) and follow the logic from your Ruby code.

or

You can use ng-repeat and in place of {{row.data}} use a function with row.data as the parameter.  The function can then handle the necessary checking for key/value.

Darryl